# Can a session be overwritten in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say that at the beginning of the run I set a variable in the session like this:

```
session[:plan_id]= "plan_id_number_in_string"
```

later in the run I want to ovewrite that value, meaning:

```
session[:plan_id]= "plan_id_2_number_in_string"
```

I'm having issues with this, can this be done?

Comment: “Im having issues with this” — please share the issue so we can address it.

Comment: Yes, this should have worked.